# How to mock LDAP Laravel auth for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, mocking, phpunit, laravel-5

In my Laravel project I use `Ldap-connector` [package](https://github.com/SaschaDens/ldap-connector) to authenticate users against LDAP

Auth works fine out of the box.

In /app/providers/AuthServiceProvider.php I have a policy defined to manage LDAP user access, for example:

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies($gate);

    $gate->define('rewards', function ($user) {
        return ($user->getAdLDAP()->inGroup('Admin') || $user->getAdLDAP()->inGroup('Marketing')) ? true : false;
    });
    // other policies 
    // ...
}
```

In the controller I check the policy for logged in user like:

```
class RewardController extends Controller {
    public function __construct($handler = null) {
        $this->authorize('rewards');
    }
    // other methods
    // ...
}
```

Everything works fine and if logged in user doesn't have `Marketing` or `Admin` group, the controller will throw `403` exception.

Now, for my `phpunit` tests I need to mock LDAP auth and provide the access to the controller to tests it's methods, otherwise policy throws me `This action is unauthorized.` error

Since ldap auth driver is implemented I don't think user model `App/User` is used and I can't just have it done with `$this->actingAs($user)` from Laravel docs from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#sessions-and-authentication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find solution by myself

I switched `LDAP` connection package to [Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel)

I used [existing unit tests](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel/blob/master/tests/AdldapTest.php) and created my own auth with `Admin` group user:

```
<?php

use Adldap\Auth\Guard;
use Adldap\Connections\Manager;
use Adldap\Connections\Provider;
use Adldap\Contracts\Connections\ConnectionInterface;
use Adldap\Laravel\Facades\Adldap;
use Adldap\Models\User;
use Adldap\Query\Builder;
use Adldap\Schemas\Schema;
use Adldap\Search\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Adldap\Models\Group;

class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
    public function pass_auth() {

        $mockedProvider = $this->mock(Provider::class);
        $mockedBuilder = $this->mock(Builder::class);
        $mockedSearch = $this->mock(Factory::class);
        $mockedAuth = $this->mock(Guard::class);
        $mockedConnection = $this->mock(ConnectionInterface::class);

        $mockedConnection->shouldReceive('isBound')->once()->andReturn(true);

        $mockedBuilder->shouldReceive('getSchema')->once()->andReturn(Schema::get());
        $mockedBuilder->shouldReceive('getConnection')->once()->andReturn($mockedConnection);

        $adUser = (new User([], $mockedBuilder))->setRawAttributes([
            'samaccountname' => ['jdoe'],
            'mail'           => ['jdoe@email.com'],
            'cn'             => ['John Doe'],
        ]);

        $manager = new Manager();
        $manager->add('default', $mockedProvider);

        Adldap::shouldReceive('getManager')->andReturn($manager);

        $mockedProvider->shouldReceive('search')->once()->andReturn($mockedSearch);
        $mockedProvider->shouldReceive('getSchema')->andReturn(Schema::get());
        $mockedProvider->shouldReceive('auth')->once()->andReturn($mockedAuth);

        $mockedSearch->shouldReceive('users')->once()->andReturn($mockedSearch);
        $mockedSearch->shouldReceive('select')->once()->andReturn($mockedBuilder);

        $mockedBuilder->shouldReceive('whereEquals')->once()->andReturn($mockedBuilder);
        $mockedBuilder->shouldReceive('first')->once()->andReturn($adUser);

        $mockedAuth->shouldReceive('attempt')->once()->andReturn(true);

        $this->assertTrue(Auth::attempt(['username' => 'jdoe', 'password' => '12345']));

        $mockedGroup = $this->mock(Group::class);
        $mockedGroup->shouldReceive('getName')->once()->andReturn('Admin');

        $mockedBuilder->shouldReceive('newInstance')->andReturnSelf();
        $mockedBuilder->shouldReceive('newCollection')->andReturn([$mockedGroup]);

    }
}
```

This part adds `Admin` group to the `user` mock

```
$mockedGroup = $this->mock(Group::class);
$mockedGroup->shouldReceive('getName')->once()->andReturn('Admin');

$mockedBuilder->shouldReceive('newInstance')->andReturnSelf();
$mockedBuilder->shouldReceive('newCollection')->andReturn([$mockedGroup]);
```